# Drop various servers - ibm db2

Tags: plsql, db2, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a script to delete multiple servers from db2 db.

To delete a single server, I can do it like this:

```
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.SERVERS WHERE servername = 'server1')
  THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SERVER server1';
 END IF;
END
```

Not I have 5 servers (server1,..., server5), so I'd like to define those servers in a variable and then using a LOOP going through them one by one and delete them if they exist.

Can you help me with this, please?
I've been reading documentation and trying, but still without success.

EDIT:

```
BEGIN
FOR C1 AS
 SELECT 'DROP SERVER "' || S.SERVERNAME || '"' AS CMD
 FROM SYSCAT.SERVERS S
JOIN (VALUES 'SERVER1', 'SERVER2', 'SERVER3', 'SERVER4', 'SERVER5') V (SERVERNAME) ON V.SERVERNAME = S.SERVERNAME
DO EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C1.CMD;
END FOR;
END
```

Comment: Too complex. `BEGIN
 FOR C1 AS 
   SELECT 'DROP SERVER "' || S.SERVERNAME || '"' AS CMD
   FROM SYSCAT.SERVERS S
   JOIN (VALUES 'SERVER1', 'SERVER2') V (SERVERNAME)
     ON V.SERVERNAME = S.SERVERNAME
  DO  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C1.CMD;
 END FOR;
END
`. Note, that if you created some Db2 objects with name surrounded by double quotes (like `CREATE SERVER "MyServer"`...), then the name is stored as case-sensitive identifier, and you must use it in the same way when you reference it in other commands. The name will be in uppercase otherwise (if you don't use double quotes).

Comment: The servers were created like this: CREATE SERVER server1...

Comment: Can you please check if its ok for 5 server solution? Because I think it will not work

Comment: If you didn't use double quotes, your constants in the code must be in upper-case unless you created your database with case-insensitive collation. The code should work for whatever number of distinct names. If you get some error, then show the error message.